# Classifying raster layer by number of equal values in given area using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, area, classification, values

I am using QGIS 3.16.12 - Hannover. I have a binary raster layer which consists of 2 values, either 0 or 1 (in my screenshots, 0 = black, 1 = white). The 1 values are scattered throughout the layer in various clusters, sometimes they are close together and may form a loose clump of 20 plus pixels, but others may only be a single pixel surrounded by 0s. Please see below image for an example of the layer.

---

[image: Example of binary raster, black = 0 and white = 1]

---

Is there a way to classify or segment this raster layer, so that I can determine clusters of value = 1 pixels (white) in a given area? For example, let me select all value = 1 (white pixels) that have a sum value of greater than 20 within a radius of 20 pixels of each other. Thereby keeping the clusters, but omitting those pixels that are all out by themselves? Please see example below.

---

[image: Example of clusters selected]

---

I can use `sieve` to sift out all the smaller clusters, but this is slightly different to picking clusters greater than 'x' pixels within 'y' area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [**r.neighbors**](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass80/manuals/r.neighbors.html)
It does exactly what you want to accomplish.

It will look at a surrounding area of n*n pixels around each pixel and give you a selected stat, in your case, the sum of all pixels.
From here you will have a density raster where you can identify the pixels exceeding a certain threshold, in your case >20.

It also allows to use a circular neighborhood setting, here is the tool's example of it:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use GRASS:s i.segment:

[image]

[image]